# Why decompiled version of IEnumerable<T> is different from source version?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, interface

I decompiled(go to the sources in `vs` using `resharper`) `IEnumerable<T>` and it contains the following code:
(some not related code is omitted here)

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{
    IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

Actually I was researching about `c#` `new` modifier and I was surprised cause `IEnumerable<T>` doesn't contain it since `IEnumerable<out T>` inherits `IEnumerable`.

Than I decided to find a real(not decompiled) sources. I went [here](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/generic/ienumerable.cs,3acf01620172c7f0,references) and found the following code:

```
public interface IEnumerable<out T> : IEnumerable
{
    new IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator();
}
```

`new` modifier is here. But now I'm confused whether `IEnumerable<T>` contains `new` modifier or not and why there's the difference.

Comment: The `new` is just there to suppress a compiler warning: Resharper's version will combine, but the compiler will give you a warning because the `IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()` method shadows `IEnumerator GetEnumerator()` from `IEnumerable`

Comment: But why do you think a `new` is needed here?

Comment: @TanveerBadar Warning CS0108 hiding inherited member

Comment: @canton7 so `new` here is just to prove our intention of hiding `GetEnumerator()` method from `IEnumerable` and nothing more - I mean practically there's no differences between `IEnumerable<T>` with `new` and `IEnumerable<T>` without `new`, right ?

Comment: Correct. The warning is just the compiler saying "... are you sure?", and the `new` is a way for you to say "Yes, I'm sure". The compiled output will be the same in both cases. Resharper should really have realised that `new` is required in order to avoid that warning

Comment: It's really a combination of two things: the need to ensure that the redeclared method is separate from the base interface method, and having done that, the need to make sure the compiler knows it was done on purpose (i.e. to prevent the warning). See separate duplicates for both the former and latter aspect.

Comment: You can also play around with [this SharpLab snippet](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA0AXEBLANgHwAEAmARgFgAoQgBgAJDSA6AYQl1xjA2wgDsAzgG4qtBqRQjKogMx1sfDDCgAzAIZgY4mQB4IAVwx0AKgD46IbVQDeVOvboBJAKJ99AW2VqM0HWboA4jAYrh5ePlAAFACUUgC+QA==) - having or removing the `new` modifier doesn't change the compiled IL code (shown on the right).

Comment: A method in a derived type cannot differ only by return type, if it does it will be considered the same method signature as an inherited method, and that's why the compiler will complain that you're shadowing the inherited method.